# kubernetes dns resolver in nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was developing locally in `docker-compose`, and had an nginx container doing a simple `proxy_pass` like so:

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://webapp:3000/;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    resolver 127.0.0.11;
}
```

I now want to move over to `kubernetes` in GKE, and the last line is giving me troubles.

I tried to switch the resolver to:

```
    resolver kube-dns;
```

I also tried various other IPs and names, but I keep getting an error along the lines of:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in resolver "kube-dns"
```

My kubernetes setup is that I have a single pod, with 2 containers: 'webapp' and 'nginx'. I simply want to have an external `service` pointing to nginx that can `proxy_pass` to webapp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25):

You have to specify the FQDN for the kube-dns and the services.
For GKE kube-dns standard for example, it would be: **kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local**
And if you're on the default namespace with your **webapp** service, it would be: **webapp.default.svc.cluster.local**

I know the original question is old, but maybe it helps someone.

Comment: So to clarify, FQDN of resolver in nginx config or the actual proxy_pass ?

Comment: resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local ipv6=off; - this also works on Digital Ocean's Kubernetes

Comment: thank you @TobiasGassmann this seems to have fixed my DNS problems with `proxy_pass`

Answer (score 4):

```
location /app {
  resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;

  proxy_pass http://webapp.default.svc.cluster.local;
}
```

This configuration with FQDN and explicit resolver (note `default` and `kube-system` explicit namespaces) worked for me (`webapp` is Kuberentes service name)

Answer (score 3):

Achieved this locally running a cluster using Kind with the below steps:

**1. Checking the DNS conf of a running pod**

`kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local home
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5
```

**2. Specifying the nameserver IP as the Nginx resolver**

```
http {
    server {
        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=10s;
```

Answer (score 1):

If nginx lives inside kubernetes there is no need to set the resolver since it will resolve to the correct spot. if `nginx` and `webapp` live in the same namespace you can simply

```
proxy_pass http://webapp
```

As long as your service name for the webapp is called webapp and using port 80.

If nginx lives outside then you should use a ingress controll or set the service for the webapp to a nodeport. A nodeport will open the same port on all the nodes so you can load balance between them on the nginx side.

Comment: This is not true if you use a variable inside the proxy_pass directive:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685674/nginx-proxy-pass-with-remote-addr

Comment: This is NOT correct.